# Resize and copy Java array in one operation

Tags: java, arrays

My code below finds position of String in array to be inserted , and then resizes the array and insert the value into copied resized, array, but it is doing so in two operations (two steps), which seems to me as inefficient.  I wonder if it is possible to resize and insert element into array in one operation.

```
 private static void insertElement(String [] words, String word){
            int i = 0;
            int size = words.length;
            for ( ; i < words.length ; i++){
                if (words[i].compareTo(word) > 0)
                break;
            }
            printArray(words);

            words = Arrays.copyOf(words, size+1);
            System.arraycopy(words, i, words, i+1, size - i);

    //      Another option : also 2 operations      
    //      String [] words2 = new String[size+1];
    //      System.arraycopy(words, 0, words2, 0, size);
    //      words = words2;
    //      System.arraycopy(words, i, words, i+1, size - i);

            words[i] = word;
            printArray(words);

        }
```

Comment: Is it required that you use an array for some reason? Otherwise, you should use an `ArrayList`, which handles this for you.

Comment: Even if something *seems* inefficient to you, it doesn't mean that it *is*. One step, two steps. It's all the same. Don't worry, your CPU can handle an extra step.

Comment: @4castle There is no requirement, just wonder if it is possible to resize and copy array in one step,  without using another data structure, which abstracts the array.

Comment: @Kayaman What if array is large? If we can avoid extra step, why not? I understand that I am talking about premature optimization, but my question if there is a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: If you think that `System.arrayCopy` is 1 step, then you're wrong. It's a series of copy operations, so doing additional things isn't going to make much of a difference in reality.

Comment: @Kayaman Two calls to `System.arrayCopy` ops is obviously two times more instructions that one call to `System.arrayCopy`. The question is not how it is implemented in native code. The question is to get rid of extra call.

Comment: You're wrong. It all depends on the size of the array and it **is** about native code. You're thinking of this the wrong way, as it's the native code that matters, not the Java code. There is no *extra* call. There's all the calls necessary. Like you said, to you it *seems* inefficient, but it's really not. It's still `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: @Kayaman Do you mean that at low level ops it is optimized and executed as a batch?

Comment: I mean that even if you had a way to write it as a single operation in Java, it would still be the same native code which does memory allocation, some `REP MOVSQ` etc. which the CPU executes quite efficiently. I guess these days when people aren't so familiar with the inner workings of computers, it can be harder to understand what is efficient and what isn't.

Comment: Let's assume it is optimized, but what about maintenance? Extra line, extra moving part, extra place for error.

Comment: That's why nobody in their right mind would bother with your code, they'd use `ArrayList` and get on with more important things. Also, if your biggest maintenance problem is having 2 lines instead of one, you're very lucky. You should try to maintain some legacy code and you'd forget all about this 1 or 2 lines of code nonsense.

Comment: @Kayaman It's not about bothering with my code, it is about answering question the right way. My question was not about compiler optimizations, and we can argue long way about two lines instead of one.

Comment: I don't think we can properly argue about this considering the difference in our experience. Your whole question is based on your feeling, and correct answers have been given below already. You should accept one of them and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [`java.util.ArrayList.add(int, Object)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) implementation, which internally uses an array also, you will see that the implementation is basically the same as yours (in terms of adding an element in the middle of an array).

So no, I don't think you will be able to accomplish what you want with arrays.

Comment: Thank you for precise answer!

Comment: The implementation of `add(int, Object)` is more efficient in that it resizes the array in exponential increments (not just increments of 1) so that most of the time it doesn't need to resize the array in order to add an element.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use an `ArrayList` as others have pointed out. Below is a code example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        words.add("Word1");
        words.add("Word2");
        words.add("Word3");

        System.out.println(String.format("Size of ArrayList: %d", words.size()));

        words.remove("Word2");

        System.out.println(String.format("Size of ArrayList: %d", words.size()));
    }
}

/* Output:
Size of ArrayList: 3
Size of ArrayList: 2
*/
```

Comment: It won't insert in lexicographical order, as required. I think I did not express my question clear enough. I wonder if it is possible to achieve it with **array** data structure itself.

Comment: @joe.d Is the array always sorted? You could use [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) to find the insertion point quicker. There's also a `Collections.binarySearch` if you choose to switch to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @4castle Yes, it is sorted, thanks for notice, thats a good point. But question is not how to find insertion point, the question is how to resize and insert in one step.